# Sorted data inserting into unordered_map

Tags: c++, sorting, unordered-map

If I insert sorted data into  `unordered_map`, when I iterate will I get the data sorted? Right now I am having issue with it. I insert sorted data but I am having unsorted data while iterating.

Comment: I think you've discovered the reason they call it "unordered".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the number of elements you are inserting is lower than the table size, that is, there are no collisions, depending on you hash function, the position calculated by his function my be related to the value itself and thus for this set of elements you have an ordered map.

For example, consider the hash function to be `x mod 10`. You insert 3 elements: `1,4,5`. 
Their hashes will be: `1,4,5` and that will be their positions in the table.

However, if you insert another element colliding with the previous inserted data the order will change. In the example, if you insert 11: `11 mod 10 = 1`, suppose the collision is solved looking for the first free position in the table, the resulting order will be: `1,11,4,5`

Comment: It's a bad idea to make *any* assumptions about the iteration order of an `unordered_map`.

Comment: @MarkRansom I absolutely agree with you. I just wanted to expose an example where a `unordered_map` could temporalily seem to be ordered when that isn´t guaranteed at all and should never be expected to.

Comment: I was hoping that's what you were trying to say, but it wasn't obvious from reading the text.

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/

> Internally, the elements in the unordered_map are not sorted in any particular order with respect to either their key or mapped values, but organized into buckets depending on their hash values to allow for fast access to individual elements directly by their key values (with a constant average time complexity on average).

Since the organization of elements relies on hash values, the order of iteration isn't necessarily affected by the order in which the elements are added.  In other words, the fact that elements read from the map aren't sorted is expected behavior.

Java offers a very handy container called a LinkedHashMap, that persevers insertion order when iterating over the collection.  Unfortunately, C++ standard libraries don't offer a built-in container for this.  The most promising thing I've seen so far is the boost::multi_index_container, but it doesn't seem trivial to setup and use.  Feel free to explore the documentation here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html